# Why need both quantity of registers and byte count when wirte multiple registers?

Tags: modbus

By MODBUS Application Protocol Specification, when write multiple registers, we need to specify both quantify of registers and byte count. 
But this document also say that "Data is packed as two bytes per register". So, we only need one of them is enough? Either quantity of registers or byte count.

In my opinion, data is not always is packed as two bytes per register. It can be three or four bytes. Is that correct? So that, we need both, is it?

Answer (score 2):

Modbus registers are always 2 bytes. For *preset multiple registers* command, byte count field is redundant. But it seems byte count field has other uses in other commands and it's not always (register count * 2). For example, see the response of the *read coil status* command (0x01). This response can contain odd number of bytes.